# How to properly apply RowMeans()? "X is not numeric" error

Tags: r

I have two columns within `OtherIncludedClean`, and I would like to add another column of `OtherIncludedClean$Mean`; however, my efforts are in vain.

I have tried:

```
OtherIncludedClean$mean <- rowMeans(OtherIncludedClean, na.rm = FALSE, dims = 1)
```

But, the above reports the error:

> "Error in base::rowMeans(x, na.rm = na.rm, dims = dims, ...) : 
>     'x' must be numeric"

I have also attempted:
 `OtherIncludedClean$mean <- apply(OtherIncludedClean, 1, function(x) { mean(x, na.rm=TRUE) })`

Which reports this error:

> "1: In mean.default(X[[i]], ...) :
>     argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA"

For all 141 rows.

Any and all help appreciated. Thank you .

My columns are `"X__1"` and `"X__2"`

Comment: The error clearly suggests to look at the `str(OtherIncludedClean)` as the columns are not numeric.  If it is a data.frame with `character` class columns `OtherIncludedClean[] <- lapplyOtherIncludedClean, as.numeric)`  If it `factor`, then convert to `character` and then to `numeric`

Answer (score 0):

When we get error `'x' must be numeric"`, it is better to check the column types.  An easier option is

```
str(OtherIncludedClean)
```

If we find that the types are not `numeric/integer` and it is `character/factor`, we need to convert it to `numeric` type (assuming that most of the values are numeric in a column and due to one or two elements which is not numeric, it changes the type).

The way to convert is `as.numeric`.  For a single column, `as.numeric(data$columnname)` if it is `character` class and for `factor` class,

```
as.numeric(as.character(data$columnname))
```

Here, we need to change all the columns to `numeric` (assuming it is `character` class).  For that, loop through the columns with `lapply` and assign the output back to the dataset

```
OtherIncludedClean[] <- lapplyOtherIncludedClean, as.numeric)
```

and then apply the `rowMeans`

If the class of only a subset of columns are `character`, then we need to only loop through those columns

```
i1 <- !sapply(OtherIncludedClean, is.numeric)
OtherIncludedClean[i1] <- lapplyOtherIncludedClean[i1], as.numeric)
```